# Button on colorbox body with external link loaded in iframe - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

I have a link bound with colorbox. Link contains external link or may be links of same site pages.

```
$('.previewLink').colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});

<a href="www.blabla.com/print/50" class="previewLink"/>HMMMMM</a>

<a href="/check/test/print/50" class="previewLink"/>HMMMMM</a>
```

Something like this. Now I want a button on the colorbox body. Similar like the close button. Functionality is simple. I want to click the button and want to go to the link that will be loaded in a new tab. Or whatever I want.

If not button,then a simple link can work for me which will take me to that site in new tab. Question is **how can I load a link on iFRAME & colorbox and get a button like close button,functionality defined by me??** I searched how to add a button in colorbox body but didn't find anything. Can anyone help?